# Internal server error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm implementing one small mvc application. I'm handling exception in Application_Error event, means I'm showing custom error page if exception occurs. But for one situation I want to show an alert message if exception occurs. But I'm not getting how to do that.

EX:

```
public PartialViewResult EditUser(int? userId, int orgId)
{
   var model = new UserViewModel();
   try
   {
      model.SelectedUser.OrgDaid = new Service.GetOrgDaid(orgId);
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
   }
   return view(model);
}
```

Service.cs:

```
public Daid GetOrgDaid(orgId)
{
   Daid daid = null;
   try
   {
      daid = daDataAccess.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == orgId && type == "Org")
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw new Exception("Daid is null");
   }
   return daid;
}
```

In above example if Exception occures in GetOrgDaid then I want to show same exception to user in alert on same view where list of User is present.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TempData to store the exception (error message) in, and show this on the page as soon as the exception occurs. I've used such a construction, looks something like this:

```
@if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <script>
        toastr.error('@Html.Raw(TempData["ErrorMessage"])', 'Error');
    </script>
}
```

Comment: It will not work for me, because I want to show an error message where the list of user is present, I don't want to show an error on  EditUser view .

Comment: The fact you _set the error message_ in the EditUser action doesn't mean that's the _only location you can show it_ :). The HTML to show the error could be anywhere on the page, and it can be displayed/shown for instance by using JavaScript. Another option is to call ```RedirectToAction``` on an exception so you go back to the list and display the error message there.

Comment: yup, I got it  ;) but I don't want render the same view again coz it will take more time, I simply want to show an error message without loading new page. So skipped the option RedirectToAction.

Answer (score 0):

Change `throw new Exception("Daid is null");` to `throw new GetOrgException("Daid is null");`. Where `GetOrgException` is a new exception that impliments `Exception`.

Then change the catch to catch this new exception:

```
catch(GetOrgException ex)
{
    model.LogException(ex);
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

Where the new LogException method you would write would extract whatever detail you want to display to the user.